# app.config migration for .net framework 4.x assemblies referenced in Core 2.0 Web API project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have a .net core web api project that references 4.x assemblies that have app.config settings.  Can I convert the app.config settings to appsettings.json without modifying the old assemblies or do I just drop in an app.config file with the settings for the older assemblies?  If I just drop in app.config files, how can I change those settings on publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing is just adding app.config files.  I also added an app.release.config and rename it to app.config as part of my publish process.  I could not use config transformations.  I could not get that to work in Azure CI at all.

Answer (score 1):

In `Core 2.0 Web API` you can point your configuration to old `app.config` as well this way:

```
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
    .AddXmlFile("app.config")
    .Build();
```

Then you will be able to access for instance your connection string (and other app settings) by the keys (looks like a colon separated XML path). For instance for the connection string section you can get the value for connection name `MyConnectionName` this way:

```
key: "connectionStrings:add:MyConnectionName:connectionString" 
value: "...your connection string..."
```

Or you can implement your own `LegacyConfigurationProvider` as described [here](http://benfoster.io/blog/net-core-configuration-legacy-projects) in details and have something like this:

```
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
    .Add(new LegacyConfigurationProvider())
    .Build();
```

See also [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration).

Comment: We are using the Core 2.0 project template in VS.  Startup.cs in that template does not use 'IConfigurationRoot' nor ConfigurationBuilder.  Those were used in Core 1.x.  Do you have an example using Core 2.0's default project template Startup.cs?

Comment: Just add public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; } property to you Startup files and then services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration); See for the details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

Comment: So make it just like Core 1.x?  I can't just add "public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }" to the existing template because it already declares "public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }".  Go create a 2.0 project from scratch so you can see what I mean.